# Where to find a large imperfect database with sample addresses for geocoding

Tags: pandas, geocode, geopy

I am looking for an imperfect database with addresses that can be used to test a geocode script.

Criteria:

1. Contain a representative sample (>10.000 entries) of global addresses
2. Contain NoData and invalid addresses to test error handling
3. Contain addresses that are ambiguous.

Nice to have:

1. Various languages(arabic, mandarin etc.)
2. Covering all continents (excl. Antarctica).
3. Addresses in various formats (street, state, city, country | zip code, city, region  etc. )
4. Easy to get into a pandas dataframe or dask

Any idea where to find this?

Answer (score 1):

Try http://geocode.xyz/Example_set.txt

We use it to draw random examples for  https://geocode.xyz/#examples

Comment: this is great. However I struggle with detecting the correct encoding. My automatic detector says UTF-8 with a 99% confidence however the resulting file has unknown characters. Or are these encoding issues introduced on purpose?  Really helpful file. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QfL08IjgGo69IeZKeuh1v9EtZsiA8QVD

Comment: also, do you have information of the correct location of each entry so you can determine geocoder accuracy and compare. I would like to compare nominatim, google maps and geocodeXYZ for isntance.

Comment: hypothesis: Addresses are UTF-8  and contains missing characters on purpose

Comment: Yes, there a mixed encodings, this is verbatim "uncleaned" data as it comes from the user. We don't have what you'd call "ground truth" for this data, i.e. human verified actual locations for each string. One way to compare is to test a given string accross many services and see where most of them agree/disagree.

Comment: There should be common misspellings of actual addresses as well. For eg., "3 Adne Edle Street, London" ( https://geocode.xyz/3%20Adne%20Edle%20Street,%20London ) -> 3 THREADNEEDLE STREET, LONDON, United Kingdom EC2R 8AY